# How can I force a major upgrade to not switch to maintenance mode using the old installation package?

Tags: windows-installer, upgrade, maintenance-mode

I have an installer that I would like to use for a major upgrade.  I have done the following:

- Increased the version number (from a.b.c to a.b.c+1)
- Changed the ProductCode
- Kept the same UpgradeCode
- Made the appropriate entry in the Upgrade table
- Changed the component ID of an existing component
- Changed the name of the installer package
- Changed the PackageCode

Basically I've done everything I can think of to force MSI to treat this as a major upgrade.

However, when I attempt to install this new package, the installer log says "Product registered: entering maintenance mode" and proceeds to try to find the old installer file (which fails, since the new installer is in a different folder than was used for the original installation, and wasn't even what I wanted to happen).

What am I missing?  Why does the installer switch to maintenance mode right away rather than perform the major upgrade?

Comment: I just noticed that Wise's VS plug-in was giving the new installer the same PackageCode as the original (even though in the UI they are different...the built MSIs have the same GUID).  I'll try fixing this, but in the meantime if anyone has ideas of what else might be wrong I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: New update:  The Wise plug-in for Visual Studio appears to have a nasty little bug in it:  If you have multiple .wsi/.wsproj in a solution, building them will give them all the same PackageCode, regardless of the actual PackageCodes assigned in the .wsi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this was due to a bug in the Wise Installer plug-in for Visual Studio.  Apparently it gets confused and starts giving the same package code to all .msi packages it generates as a part of the build (regardless of the package code in the .wsi file).